# Adding from within from runat server asp.net

Tags: asp.net, paypal, multiple-forms

I am having a signup page at the upper of the page there is a form tag that is runat server. I want to add a code that is given by paypal take payment. That code contains a simple html controls not asp.net controls but when i paste to the code to the page then it don't submit it to the action it postback the form and don't do with paypal code at all. when i checked the source of the code it doesn't shows the from tag given by the paypal. it doesn't rander the form given by the paypal. I also have to take the form at top because my page has asp.net controls that's why that is necessary.

Please tell the solution

Comment: I needed to use the following mentioned code solution provided isn't working with it.
'<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LL5LZEB8L6T8S" />
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif"
name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
width="1" height="1" />
</form>'

Answer (score 0):

You must not use asp.net form tag in asp.net while payment processing.

Use this

```
<body onload="document.paypal.submit();">
  <form name="paypal" action='<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPalSubmitUrl"] %>'
method="post">

      // rest html goes here

  </form>
</body>
```

I always do it like this for paypal processing

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using PayPal Standard.

If so, collect submitted values from (regular ASP.Net) form. Then forward them to PayPal like this -

```
protected void SubmitRadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string paypalUrl = IsTestMode ? 
        "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr" : 
        "https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr";

    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append(paypalUrl);
    builder.AppendFormat("?cmd=_xclick&business={0}", EmailTextBox.Text);
    builder.Append("&lc=US&no_note=0&currency_code=USD");
    builder.AppendFormat("&item_name={0}", ItemNameHiddenField.Value);

    builder.AppendFormat("&amount={0}", AmountTextBox.Text);
    builder.AppendFormat("&return={0}", ReturnUrl);
    builder.AppendFormat("&cancel_return={0}", CancelUrl);

    builder.AppendFormat("&undefined_quantity={0}", 1);
    builder.AppendFormat("&item_number={0}", ItemNumberHiddenField.Value);

    builder.AppendFormat("&cpp_header_image={0}", HeaderImage);

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I needed to use the following mentioned code and also need to prepare the session on the page and also having multiple asp.net controls. So, I needed to take my form as runat server and the above mentioned method doesn't work in my case for paypal subscription. If there is any more solution in this please share it

Comment: Your code doesn't work in ASP.Net. I updated the code. It basically collects the user submitted form (after button click event), and post them to PayPal.

Answer (score -1):

I tried the same but didn't work. Please see my paypal code that they provided and let me know how to do this. I have tried the above method previously but this time isn't working with code. May be it is for subscription code different. Read the code following and let me know about how to use this.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                            <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="LL5LZEB8L6T8S" />
                            <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif"
                                name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
                            <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif"
                                width="1" height="1" />
                            </form>
```

Thanks

Comment: I needed to use the above mentioned code and also need to prepare the session on the page and also having multiple asp.net controls. So, I needed to take my form as runat server and the above mentioned method doesn't work in my case for paypal subscriptoin. If there is any more solution in this please share it.